# Laravel elfinder resize and copy uploaded image to multiple dimensions

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack, elfinder

Hello I'm using **backpack** which uses **elfinder** as a file manager, and i want to achive te following: 
when an image is uploaded I want to create 3 copies of it

1. one with it real dimension
2. the second is 200x200
3. and the third 50x50

Note: Like WordPress which has this mechanism built in (uploading multiple sizes of the image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do that thanks to elFinder itself. The [PHP package for elFinder](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder) doesn't have events or anything like that, for you to customize its upload behaviour. And doing it in Javascript would probably not be a good idea.

But thanks to Backpack, there's one thing you could do, that could be useful. You can [use Model Events](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-operation-create#use-events-in-your-setup-method) inside your CrudControllers, to do stuff after the cretate/update form has been submitted. For example:

- when the `updated` event happens, check if that file that was upload (with real dimensions) has thumbnails; if so, do nothing;
- if not, create the thumbnails using a library like [Intervention image](https://image.intervention.io/v2) that is already included in Backpack;

So it would looks something like this:

```php
public function setup()
{

    // ...

    Product::saved(function($entry) {
        if (!$entry->hasThumbnailsForAttachment()) {
            $entry->generateThumbnailsForAttachment()
        }
    });
}
```

Then in your Model you could create these two methods, `hasThumbnailsForAttachment()` and `generateThumbnailsForAttachment()`.

Hope it helps!